# I am getting error in sql query ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 INSERT INTO MANPOWER.VIPBADGE ( 
           DOC_SRL, GRP_CD, DOC_TYPE, REC_TYPE, MV_MT, VESS_NAME, VESS_TYPE, IMO_NO, CALL_SIGN, REG_PORT, 
            AGENCY_FUN_CD, AGENCY_CD, EX_VESS_NAME, EX_CALL_SIGN, VESS_FLAG, SAT_ID, SATCOM_ID, FREE_BOARD, VESS_BLD_DT, VESS_BLD_PLACE,
            DT_OF_DELI, PERMANENT_VALIDTY, SHIP_REG_CERT_NO, SHIP_REG_VALDT, SAFETY_MGMT_CERT_NO, SAFETY_MGMT_CERT_VALDT, VESS_HT, ISPS_COMPL, CAP2_CERT, BEAM, 
           LOA, LBP, MAX_DRAFT, PARL_BODY_LN, BOW_TO_MANIFOLD, GRT, NRT, DWT, SUMMER_DEAD_WT, TEU_CAP, 
            SBT, REDU_GRT, VESS_OWN, EMAIL_ID, CLASSFN_SOCIETY, HULL_INS_COMP_NAME, HULL_INS_COMP_VALDT, ENGN_TYPE, NO_OF_ENGN, ENGN_POWER, 
            PROPULSION_TYPE, NO_OF_PROPELLERS, NO_OF_BAYS, NO_OF_ROWS_ON_DECK, HATCH_COVER_TYPE, NO_OF_HATCH, MAX_MAN_SPEED, BOW_THRUSTER, BOW_THRUSTER_NO, BOW_THRUSTER_POWER, 
           STERN_THRUSTER_NO, STERN_THRUSTER_POWER, BULBOUS_BOW, MMSI_NO, PORT_APPR, APPR_BY, APPR_DT, ACTION_FLAG, ENTRY_BY, ENTRY_DT ) VALUES ( 
           '8735910', 'VRD', 'VESPRO', 'N', 'MT', 'KDS TANKER 1', '153', '170224', '5778568', 'INMAA1', 'VA', '70009330', ' ', ' ', 'IN', ' ',
            ' ', '1', TO_DATE('01/01/2023','dd/MM/yyyy'), ' ', ' ', 'N', '6527849 ',  TO_DATE('31/12/2025', 'dd/MM/yyyy'), '7539234578', 
            TO_DATE('28/12/2025', 'dd/MM/yyyy'), ' ', 'Y', 'N', '30.00', '120.00', '100.00', '10.00', ' 90.000', ' ', '1000.0', ' 
            500.0', '1500.0', ' ', ' ', 'N', ' ', 'RAM ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '', 'DIESEL', '2', ' ', 'DIESEL', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '14.0', 'Y', '2', 
           ' ', '2', ' ', 'N', ' ', 'INKKK1', ' admin001',TO_DATE('17/02/2025', 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'Y', ' ADMIN',SYSDATE )
```

I have provided all the dates in correct format but still getting error : `ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month` Please explain me why ?

Comment: is this java or javascript? and, honestly, the error seems clear and self explanatory. It's not complaining about the format, this is the kind of mess you would get if you tried to parse '30/02/2005', because even in a leap year, February only has 29 days.

Comment: I'd *start* by working out which field is causing the problem, reducing it to a *minimal* insert. I'd also suggest editing the question to either remove the java and javascript tags *or* explaining why you think they're relevant.

Comment: What is the value of SYSDATE? Maybe your pc date locale has a different format than the database.

Comment: Its not a JavaScript Code, Its a Oracle Database query I am facing issue in only parsing Date also SYSDATE is not causing issue I have tried to change SYSDATE. above dates are causing issues

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+sql+"ORA-01847"+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: But don't use snippets for SQL code...

Answer (score 3):

Who knows; you should have also posted table **description** which specifies which columns are `DATE`s.

Reviewing that query, it looks as if "dt" represents "date". If that's so, there are 7 columns:

```
INSERT INTO manpower.vipbadge (vess_bld_dt,                                           -- 1
                               dt_of_deli,                                            -- 2
                               ship_reg_valdt,                                        -- 3
                               safety_mgmt_cert_valdt,                                -- 4
                               hull_ins_comp_valdt,                                   -- 5
                               appr_dt,                                               -- 6
                               entry_dt)                                              -- 7
     VALUES (TO_DATE ('01/01/2023', 'dd/MM/yyyy'),                                    -- 1
             ' ',                                                                     -- 2
             TO_DATE ('31/12/2025', 'dd/MM/yyyy'),                                    -- 3
             TO_DATE ('28/12/2025', 'dd/MM/yyyy'),                                    -- 4
             ' ',                                                                     -- 5
             TO_DATE ('17/02/2025', 'dd/MM/yyyy'),                                    -- 6
             SYSDATE                                                                  -- 7
           );
```

- some of them have `TO_DATE` with format mask that matches values
- `sysdate` is a function that returns `date` datatype
- there are two column (`dt_of_deli` and `hull_ins_comp_valdt` that *look* suspicious, as you're putting a *space* into them. That might be cause of error you got.

Demo:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, some_date date);

Table created.
```

Putting space into `some_date`:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, some_date) values (1, ' ');
insert into test (id, some_date) values (1, ' ')
                                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month


SQL>
```

Therefore, review these two columns. If you want them to be empty, then insert `NULL` into them, not a space:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, some_date) values (1, null);

1 row created.

SQL>
```